# Iam trying to insert 1 milion row in mongodb (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to insert 1 million records in mongodb it take so much time while many
says that it can do it so fast tell me please what's wrong with my code
i'm using php to do that

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";

$collection = $db->createCollection("mycol");
echo "Collection created succsessfully";

$collection = $db->mycol;
echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++)
{
    $document = array( 
        "title" => "MongoDB".$i, 
        "description" => "database", 
        "likes" => 100,
        "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
        "by" => "tutorials point"
     );

     $collection->insert($document);
}

echo "Document inserted successfully";
```

Comment: How long is `so much time`, and what do you believe/expect to be `so fast`?

Comment: i expect it can do it in 2 minutes

Comment: How long does it take, and where did you get the expectation that it could do it in 2 minutes? And do you really believe that a single PHP Thread can handle 1000000 insertions in 2 minutes? Do you have a business requirement to handle 1000000 insertions in a single request? Have you tried running 1000 threads inserting 1000 entries each?

Comment: it take so much then device hang i will tell you full details i am android developer and only know sql and some php to create web services i create an application and now number of users increased and number of records became 1 million i asked and someone said to me use mongodb it can insert and select so fast so i did and now it's not fast as i expected

Comment: Use batched/bulk inserts.

Comment: But if you have 1 million users, they're not all connecting simultaneously to the same PHP thread to insert their million records. each request runs in its own thread, and that thread performs a single insert..... so your script above is simulating the wrong thing.... you need to simulate 1000000 individual threads, each one doing 1 insert

Comment: yes i know man but now first i need to insert 1 million record then start to test users moves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Batched / Bulk Inserts](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php) instead:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();

$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";
$collection = $db->createCollection("mycol");

$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";
$collection = $db->mycol;

$batchSize = 1000;
$documents = array();
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++)
{
      $documents[] = array( 
            "title" => "MongoDB".$i, 
            "description" => "database", 
            "likes" => 100,
            "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
            "by" => "tutorials point"
      );

      // If we've reached `$batchSize` entries, perform the batched insert.
      if (($i+1) >= $batchSize)
      {
            $collection->batchInsert($documents);
            $documents = array();
      }
}

// Finish the last batch.
if (!empty($documents))
{
      $collection->batchInsert($documents);
}
```

Here, we insert 1000 records at a time (adjustable via `$batchSize`). This requires MongoDB 2.6 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage your insert operations by using the [Bulk Operations API](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/) which is available from MongoDB 2.6 and greater. The current PHP driver should support these methods, where in particular you need the **[`MongoWriteBatch`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongowritebatch.php)** class for insert operations, in particular create an Insert Write Batch with the **[`MongoInsertBatch`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoinsertbatch.php)** class:

```
<?php
    $mc = new MongoClient("localhost");
    $collection = $mc->selectCollection("test", "category");

    $batch = new MongoInsertBatch($collection);
    $counter = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {

        $document = array( 
            "title" => "MongoDB".$i, 
            "description" => "database", 
            "likes" => 100,
            "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
            "by", "tutorials point"
        );
        $batch->add($document);
        $counter++;

        if ( $counter % 1000 === 0 ) {
            $ret = $batch->execute(array("w" => 1));
            $counter++;
            $batch = new MongoInsertBatch($collection);        
        }
    }

    if ( $counter > 0 ) {
        $ret = $batch->execute(array("w" => 1));
    }
?>
```

In the above, each document created in the for loop is added to an insert operation which is then added to a batch via the `.add()` method, and is only sent to the server on the call to `.execute()`. Ordered write write operations are sent to the server, in the order provided, for serial execution. If a write fails, any remaining operations will be aborted.

There is some management of the "size" of these operations implemented with the modulo operation, which should be generally handled by the driver but keeps this in manageable sizes should you want to check the write result.

The key here is that rather than waiting for the write response from the server for every single update, the operations are sent and responded to in "batches". The reduction in "overhead" here when performing mass updates is considerable as there is less "back and forth" when communicating with the server.

Comment: We had the same idea! :)

Comment: @Will You can say that again, in both methods, the driver uses the underlying bulk api to do the inserts in batches.